# Find duration in video in paperclip-ffmpeg in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, ffmpeg

Using gem paperclip-ffmpeg in rails for videos.It works fine now I want to find the duration of video in seconds.I found some material but nothing works like

```
result = `ffmpeg -i #{self.video.to_file.path} 2>&1`
r = result.match("Duration: ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).([0-9]+)")
if r
  self.duration = r[1].to_i*3600+r[2].to_i*60+r[3].to_i
end
```

But it gives error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_file' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x000000071d9b18>
```

How I find video length?

Comment: Maybe try a specialized library? https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

Comment: THere a issue Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ffmpeg -i /home/user/projects/test/public/aaa.mov